# FosUserBundle after login redirect

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, fosuserbundle

how can I redirect after login based on your role?
for example, user: admin, role: ROLE_ADMIN in /admin and user: standard, role: ROLE_USER in /user?

Comment: see this  [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11506155/how-to-redirect-to-different-url-based-on-roles-in-symfony-2)

Comment: I apologize for not having a good look at the above questions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `eventlistener` to listen onInteractiveLogin event.

here you got some examples: http://www.reecefowell.com/2011/10/26/redirecting-on-loginlogout-in-symfony2-using-loginhandlers/ http://www.metod.si/login-event-listener-in-symfony2/

Here is explained entire `FOS` Logic:
http://blog.logicexception.com/2011/10/symfony2-securitybundle-and.html

Comment: Great!!!
The first solution is the best in my opinion!
Thanks