# Symfony redirect after login with condition on user

Tags: redirect, authentication, symfony

My symfony3 login page redirects to home by default, as stated inside my `security.yml` file.

However, I want it to redirect to my "Edit profile" page if the user didn't fulfil it yet. In any other form I would make this in the controller, but since there is no `$form->handleRequest($user)` in the login form, I don't have a `$user` variable to test on.

There is a lot of SO topics about how to redirect user based on roles, and the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login.html) tells about redirecting from the action field of the form or within `security.yml`, but not any is what I'm looking for.

How can I redirect based on a condition ?

NB : for some reasons, I cannot use FOSUserBundle yet :-(

Comment: You can redirect inside the form with a custom input like that : http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login.html

Comment: This is the exact same link that I prodived you know...

Comment: Oops.. A way to do may be to use the session/cookie and redirect if it's empty. http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html#setting-cookies / http://api.symfony.com/3.2/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Cookie.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11506155/how-to-redirect-to-different-url-based-on-roles-in-symfony-2 here I found what I need

Answer (score 7):

I assume you are using the Guard Authentication system. ( http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/guard_authentication.html )

Then you should have a class extending the `AbstractGuardAuthenticator` class.

In that class, there is a method called `onAuthenticationSuccess`, in here you can put some logic for redirecting the request.
If you return `null` here, it will just continue, and use the route configured in your security.yml.

You will need to pass the `@router` service to the Authenticator class through dependencyInjection.

Assuming you passed the router service, your method will look something like this:

```
public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
{
    /** @var User $user */
    $user = $token->getUser();

    if ($user->hasCompleteProfile() == false) {
        $url = $this->router->generate('edit_profile');

        return new RedirectResponse($url);
    }

    // Continue with default behaviour
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Actually, I used [a Simple Registration Form](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/registration_form.html), and a [a Traditional Login Form](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html). I'll look into the Guard Authentication system, but the website I'm building is not due to have a rock-hard security so maybe it is an overkill...

Comment: What if in my case there is no extended AbstractGuardAuthenticator - I dont find such in my project? And if I dont want 2 redirects, they are slowing page down. Then only way to refactor to use AbstractGuardAuthenticator ? Or any other there is?

Answer (score 5):

If all else fails (or becomes an excessive pain to deal with) you can always simply introduce an intermediary route and do your logic in there.

That is, create an action who's sole purpose is to redirect users based on whatever logic is needed, and then put that as the target path in the `security.yml` firewall.

```
security:
    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            anonymous: ~
            form_login: 
                login_path: login
                check_path: login
                default_target_path: login_success
                always_use_default_target_path: true
            logout:
                path: logout
```

Where the login would be something like:

```
class AuthenticationController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/login", name="login")
     * @Route("/logout", name="logout")
     */
    public function loginAction(Request $request)
    {
        // Standard login stuff here
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/login_success", name="login_success")
     */
    public function postLoginRedirectAction()
    {
        if (/* user needs to see location A */) {
            return $this->redirectToRoute("location_a");
        } else if (/* user needs to see location B */) {
            return $this->redirectToRoute("location_b");
        } else {
            return $this->redirectToRoute("index");
        }
    }
}
```